# Sheets macro script edit for filter reset

Tags: google-sheets-api

I use buttons to reset and set all the filters. Now I need to manually set one of the filters on the same row (N14), and I don't want the scrips to change it or reset it. How can it be done?

```
    function RESET() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B14:O14').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B14:O926').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H15:O100').activate();
};

function RULEX() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D14').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextEqualTo('Rule')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, criteria);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E14').activate();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenTextEqualTo('No')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
};
```

Comment: Can you add in more detail? Can you add in a sample sheet? You say that you want the script to modify the filters, but then you also say that you want the script to leave the filters alone.